# 7zip command to extract with full paths (excluding first folder level)

Tags: windows, 7-zip, extract

Using 7zip command line version, I need to extract a `.7z` file with full paths but excluding the first folder level within the archive.

I thought that this command below would work but it still extracts the "chrome-win32" folder instead of its content.

```
7z x "chromium.7z"  -o"C:\Apps\1\chromium\"  -ir!"chrome-win32\*"  -y
```

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077667/7zip-command-to-extract-with-full-paths-excluding-first-folder-level) to multiple stack-exchange sites.

Comment: I believe you're missing \ before `*`. This way it matches only `chrome-win32` folder. Also be avare that `*` does not match files starting with `.`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is cheating, but it would work....

`7z x chromium.7z -o"C:\Apps\1\" -y && move "c:\Apps\1\chrome-win32" "c:\Apps\1\chromium"`